# Smallest alphabet with maximum occurences in python string

Tags: python, scripting

There is a python string for example "programming"
I have to find the smallest letter with highest occurrences.

That is for given input string = "programming"
the output should be `g 2`

I tried this , but not able to achieve the solution

```
str1 = 'programming'


max_freq = {}
for i in str1:
    if i in max_freq:
        max_freq[i] += 1
    else:
        max_freq[i] = 1
res = max(max_freq, key = max_freq.get)
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by smallest alphabet?

Comment: Do you mean by the ASCII code

Comment: yes, Its meant for ascii code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` and achieve this.

- Count the frequency of each letter using `Counter`. This will give you a `dict`
- Sort the `dict` first by the values in descending order and then by the keys value in ascending order
- The First item is your answer

```
from collections import Counter
str1 = 'programming'
d = Counter(str1)

d = sorted(d.items(), key= lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
print(d[0])
```

```
('g', 2)
```

For your code to work, replace the last line with this

```
res = sorted(max_freq.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[0]
```

`res` will have the smallest letter with maximum occurrences. i.e, `('g', 2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was very stressed about this problem

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just aren't getting the max correctly.  If all you care about is the number, then you could modify your example slightly:

```
str1 = 'programming'


max_freq = {}
for i in str1:
    if i in max_freq:
        max_freq[i] += 1
    else:
        max_freq[i] = 1
res = max(max_freq.values())
```